# Should the packets generated from the system verilog generator module be destroyed to save simulation time?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, uvm

Every time when I call the `generate_directed_packet` a new object is created. Should I worry about deleting the packet object, before creating the next one. If so, how should I go about deleting the packet object?

```
function void generate_directed_packet();
packet = new();
void'(packet.randomize());
endfunction : generate_directed_packet
```

Answer (score 2):

SystemVerilog has automatic memory management. That means it only holds an object around as long as there is a class variable containing a handle to that object. The simulator "deletes" the object after there are no more class variables with a handle to that object. The "delete" is in quotes because you have no knowledge of when it deletes the object. More likely it keeps the space around until another new() of the same object and reclaims the space.

If you are using the UVM, the typical case is you are generating packets in a sequence, and sending them to a driver. What you are really doing is creating a handle to a new object in the sequence, and then copying the handle from variables in the sequence to variables in the driver.

As you copy the handle from one variable to another, you are erasing the reference to the older object. So as long as you are put putting handles to your objects in data structure that grows as you add more object handles to it, the space from the old objects get reclaimed.